# Customizing contacts display in iPhone app using ABPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, contacts, abpersonviewcontroller

Our application uses the ABPersonViewController class to display the iPhone's contacts.  I see that when I display a contact, there are no "action" buttons displayed, such as "Text Message" or "Add to Favorites".  When accessing the native Contacts app, these buttons are displayed for the same contact.

1) Does anyone know why the same "action" buttons would not be displayed when using ABPersonViewController ?

2) Is it possible to add custom "action" buttons to the displayed contact view when using ABPersonViewController?

Thanks,

- Ken

Answer (score 0):

Using the **ABUnknownPersonViewController** the [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABUnknownPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) allowsActions and allowsAddingToAddressBook properties are to allow the actions you mentioned to add a contact to the Contacts.

Comment: @pre Let me answer the questions then: 1) because Contacts app either doesn't use ABPersonViewController or use it's undocumented features 2) no, as far as they are not added to the ABPersonViewController code and documented. Please let me know if this answers (which I believe are complete) help you better than the answer above, that provides you a way of using some (maybe not every) of the needed actions.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. `ABPersonViewController` wont show "action" buttons. Customizing this view is also not possible.